# Decrease 1 year from a string in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, substring

I have a string in SQL Server. I need help as I am new to SQL.

```
DECLARE @a varchar(50) = 201207
```

I want if last 2 chars are less than `7`, then year should be decreased to output `201107`, else it should be `201307`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this and hope it helps you:

If last 2 char is less than equal to 7 then it gives output '201107' else it gives '201307'

```
declare  @a varchar(50)=201207

If substring(@a,5,2) <= 7
begin
Set @a = cast(SUBSTRING(@a,1,4) -1 as varchar(4)) + substring(@a,5,2)
end
else
begin
Set @a = cast(SUBSTRING(@a,1,4) +1 as varchar(4)) + substring(@a,5,2)
end

select @a
```

Answer (score 0):

You can as the below:

```
DECLARE @Val VARCHAR(10) = '201206'
SELECT CASE WHEN  RIGHT(@Val, 2) * 1 <= 7  THEN CAST(LEFT(@Val, 4) * 1 - 1 AS VARCHAR(4))
            ELSE CAST(LEFT(@Val, 4) * 1 + 1 AS VARCHAR(4)) END + RIGHT(@Val, 2)
```

Result: `201106`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DECLARE @a  VARCHAR(50)=201206,
        @dt DATE

SET @dt = Cast(@a + '01' AS DATE)

SELECT CASE
         WHEN Month(@dt) < 7 THEN LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Dateadd(yyyy, -1, @dt), 112), 6)
         ELSE LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Dateadd(yyyy, 1, @dt), 112), 6)
       END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @a varchar(50)=201412
Select Case when Cast(Substring(@a,5,2) AS INT) >=7
       THEN Cast(Cast(Substring(@a,1,4) AS INT)+1 AS nvarchar)+(Substring(@a,5,2))
       ELSE Cast(Cast(Substring(@a,1,4) AS INT)-1 AS nvarchar)+(Substring(@a,5,2)) 
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
DECLARE @a varchar(50) = 201207
select case when cast(right(@a,2) as int) < 7 then @a - 100  else @a + 100 end as date
```